# How to initialize a vector of vectors on a struct?

Tags: c++, vector

If I have a NxN matrix

```
vector< vector<int> > A;
```

How should I initialize it?

I've tried with no success:

```
 A = new vector(dimension);
```

neither:

```
 A = new vector(dimension,vector<int>(dimension));
```

Comment: You should probably consult an introductory book. new returns a pointer to what it has allocated (and is not needed here anyway).

Comment: vector<vector<int>> MyMatrix[4][4]; //works as well

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. The supposed linked duplicate is for a different question, for which the top answer also answers this question, but you won't find it when searching for this question.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You use `new` to perform dynamic allocation. It returns a pointer that points to the dynamically allocated object.

You have no reason to use `new`, since `A` is an automatic variable. You can simply initialise `A` using its constructor:

```
vector<vector<int> > A(dimension, vector<int>(dimension));
```

Comment: Ok, I found my problem. I didn't mention that I have a pointed struct, which have that vector. And doing what u say: myStructVble->A(dimension, vector<int>(dimension)); , it throws me "function doesn't match".

Comment: @LiLou_ You'll have to initialise it the struct's constructor. Or copy from a temporary to the member: `myStructVble->A = vector<vector<int>>(dimension, vector<int>(dimension));`

Answer (score 15):

Like this:

```
#include <vector>

// ...

std::vector<std::vector<int>> A(dimension, std::vector<int>(dimension));
```

(Pre-C++11 you need to leave whitespace between the angled brackets.)